# Spring H2 JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException after a modification in database

Tags: spring-boot, exception, spring-data-jpa, h2

I successfully insert a data in TABLE_A, then I close the application and update id field manually from 1 to 2 and start application again,
while inserting a new entity to TABLE_A , I get Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.TABLE_A(ID) ( /* key:2 */ 2

In my entity class, Id field is defined as:

```
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer id;
```

How can I make it to check/calculate the Id before insert?

I already checked
IDENTITY, AUTO, TABLE for the strategy

Answer (score 0):

As you changed id manually the auto increment id will not be changed. So when you try to insert new record it took id 2 which you have already taken. You need to reset the auto increment with new id.

Use following query to change id. Assuming your table name is `PUBLIC.TABLE_A` and column name is `ID`

```
ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.TABLE_A ALTER COLUMN ID RESTART WITH 3
```

If you using sequence then you need to RESTART sequence.

Comment: So there is no way to do it automatically. for example if there are records in table with id 2,4,7,9.. I cannot set it to 3 because It will hit 4 in the next insert...I want it to insert 1,3,5,6,8,10 etc.. automatically.

Comment: No. Auto increment will update it automatically. If you have data with different IDS then you should insert id from your code instead of generating ID in DB. If you still want to use auto increment then you should find max id from existing record and set auto increment id higher than that.

Comment: ok... that's bad 
thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue:

Reset the Primary Key:
You might want to reset the ID field in TABLE_A to its original state, ensuring that it follows a proper sequence or uses an auto-increment feature (if applicable). This will prevent conflicts when inserting new records.

**If that doesn't work, try reconfiguring
the original value**, ex:

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "my_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "my_seq", sequenceName = "YOUR_SEQUENCE_NAME", initialValue = 1000, allocationSize = 1)
private Long id;

Comment: currently I'm already using seq.generators and in every start I set it to the id max value+50 but
for example if there are records in table with id 2,4,7,9.. I want it to insert 1,3,5,6,8,10 etc.. automatically and I don't want to use seq generators